# Undefined method `=' when '=' is nowhere in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `=' for #<CabinetItem:0x490e6f0>
```

None of my code uses an equal sign.  Can you see a problem?  Thanks.

View call:

```
<%= link_to "Toggle", {:controller => :cabinet_items, :action => :toggle_backmount, :id => cabinet_item.id } %>
```

controlloer method:

```
def toggle_backmount
    @cabinet_item = CabinetItem.find(params[:id])
    @cabinet_item.toggle_backmount

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

model method:

```
def toggle_backmount
    if self.is_backmount
      self.update_attribute(is_backmount, false)
    else
      self.update_attribute(is_backmount, true)
    end
  end
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
#<Class:0x5f0ea28>: undefined method `=' for #<CabinetItem:0x7becc28>
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib
/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/li
b/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/li
b/active_record/persistence.rb:180:in `update_attribute'
        from C:/Users/n0222072/AptanaWorkspace/dcms/app/models/cabinet_item.rb:4
8:in `toggle_backmount'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/ra
ils/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/ra
ils/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/SOFTWARE/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/ra
ils/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please show the exact, complete stack trace. Obviously some of your code uses a setter, because you show it in `toggle_backmount`, but it's unclear if that's the `=` referred to.

Comment: I think you want a symbol when calling `update_attribute`: `self.update_attribute(:is_backmount, false)`

Comment: @PeterHuene, that is correct.  Just saw it myself.

Comment: It will be better named `toggle_backmount!` (as it changes and saves models), and also write whole method `update_attribute(:is_backmount, !is_backmount)`.

Comment: Unrelated to the OP's issue - but for those getting an error for a property that does not exist on the object/class referenced - try restarting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `update_attribute` should be a string or a symbol. As it is, you're calling `is_backmount` and passing the result of that as the first argument to `update_attribute`. Apparently in this case, `is_backmount` is returning nil. You want:

```
def toggle_backmount
  if self.is_backmount
    self.update_attribute(:is_backmount, false)
  else
    self.update_attribute(:is_backmount, true)
  end
end
```